# Cannot find .ts module while running node script with experimental-modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am working on node express project. I want to run node script from terminal. In my project i've some .ts files that i want to call in that script (MyScript.js).

Here is MyScript.js

```
import get from 'lodash/get';
import every from 'lodash/every';
import UserEntity from '../../../server/models/User'; // .js file
import UserService from '../../../server/services/UserService';// .ts file

const execute = async () => {/* some code */};
execute();
```

From command line i try to execute MyScript.js like this

```
node --experimental-modules src/scripts/.mjs
```

I got the following error

```
(node:27608) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
{ Error: Cannot find module ../../server/services/UserService
at search (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:29:12)
at Loader.resolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/default_resolve.js:65:11)
at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:58:33)
at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:113:40)
at ModuleWrap.promises.module.link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:32:40)
at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:31:36) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Any idea how to call a .ts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a there are a few misconceptions here.

1. Typescript must be [compiled](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html) to javascript first if you want to run it.
2. `--experimental-modules` allows you to use es module format, it doesn't relate to typescript.

To *'directly'* run typescript you can use [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node). This tool basically runs the typescript compiler and pipes the result to node.

Answer (score 0):

TS files are [typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) files. You have to compile it to JavaScript then you can use it.

Comment: Install typescript globally. As you have tsconfig.json file so from your project directory run `tsc -p .`